# displaying own like count next to like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website where the URLs have some tracking parameters that do not affect the page that is displayed i.e. the URL is of the form http://mywebsite.com/page1?tracking1=aaa&tracking2=bbb and 'tracking1' and 'tracking2' are just tracking parameters used for some other purpose and do no determine the page that is displayed. The page that is displayed is always 'http://mywebsite.com/page1' irrespective of the values of these tracking parameters.

I have included the facebook like button on my website pages and facebook treats each of these URLs, including the tracking parameters, as separate pages. I'm not able to get facebook to ignore these tracking parameters and just consider the URL without tracking parameters as a page. So, I'm storing my own like count against the actual URL (when I get a callback on the like action) and displaying it next to the like button.

Is displaying own like count next to facebook like button against their usage policy? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Implement proper Open Graph meta tags, and tell Facebook that what the canonical address for these different URLs is via `og:url`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular functional reason you're using GET (ie URL) variables to store your tracking?

If you can push them into POST instead, or use cookies or sessions for your tracking, you can simplify your URLs and Facebook should treat it as a single page.

If you have to use GET due to, for example, the links coming from external websites, you could use a pass-through URL to do your tracking, before forwarding to the main page. ie someone clicks the link to redirect?tracking1=aaa&tracking2=bbb&page=page1

And redirect, as you may have guessed, does what you need to do with your tracking before forwarding the user on to page1.